# whereDoesntHave not working with hasMany relationship as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

Each target has many certs.

```
certs
target_id uploaded
1         1
1         0
```

I want to get targets that do not have any uploaded certs (`uploaded = 0`). The following query still return target 1 while it should return nothing!

```
Target::whereDoesntHave('certs', function ($query) { 
    $query->where('uploaded', 0);
})->get();
```

and the query that laravel produce is:

```
SELECT * FROM `targets`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `certs`
    WHERE `targets`.`id` = `certs`.`target_id` AND `uploaded` = 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `doesntHave`

```
  Target::doesntHave('certs','and', function ($query) { $query->where('uploaded', 0); })->get()
```

**Updated**

```
 Target::with(['certs'])->whereHas('certs', function ($query) { $query->where('uploaded', 0); })->get()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it makes the exact same wrong query

Comment: let me give a try .few min

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is fetching all Targets that don't have any non-uploaded certs i.e. where **doesn't** have certs where upload is 0.

You should be able to get what you want by changing `0` to `1` i.e. get all targets that don't have any uploaded certs:

```
Target::whereDoesntHave('certs', function ($query) {
    $query->where('uploaded', 1);
})->get();
```